# PHP - nikic/FastRoute routes for Middlewares\FastRoute package

Tags: php, routes, fastroute

I have got these route:

```
['GET', '/article/{id}', ['SuperBlog\Controller\ArticleController', 'show']],
```

and I am using `Middleware\FastRoute`, `Middle\RequestHandler` and `Relay` packages to make a Request Handler. Also I am using `php-di` DI container.

My problem is that if I want to use a route like mentioned above, i gaves me this error:

`Deprecated: Non-static method SuperBlog\Controller\ArticleController::show() should not be called statically in`

It works well when I don't use methods (like `['GET', '/', 'SuperBlog\Controller\HomeController'],`).

My question is how can I make it work? Didn't find any solution. I know that if I make the `show` method static it will work, but I don't think it's a good idea.

**bootstrap.php**

```
 /**
 * Routing
 */
$routes = simpleDispatcher(function (RouteCollector $r){
   $routes = include('routes.php');
    foreach ($routes as $route) {
        $r->addRoute($route[0], $route[1], $route[2]);
    }
});

$middlewareQueue[] = new FastRoute($routes);
$middlewareQueue[] = new RequestHandler($container);

$requestHandler = new Relay($middlewareQueue);
$response = $requestHandler->handle(ServerRequestFactory::fromGlobals());
$emitter = new SapiEmitter();
return $emitter->emit($response);
```

**ArticleController.php**

```
class ArticleController
{

    /**
     * @var ArticleRepository
     */
    private $articleRepository;

    /**
     * @var Twig_Environment
     */
    private $twig;


    /**
     * @var ResponseInterface
     */
    private $response;

    public function __construct(ArticleRepository $articleRepository, Twig_Environment $twig, ResponseInterface $response) {
        $this->articleRepository = $articleRepository;
        $this->twig = $twig;
        $this->response = $response;
    }


    public function show($request) {
        $article = $this->articleRepository->get($request->getAttribute('id'));

        $this->response->getBody()->write($this->twig->render('article.twig',[
            'article' => $article,
        ]));

        return $this->response;
    }

}
```

**routes.php**

```
return [
    ['GET', '/', 'SuperBlog\Controller\HomeController'],
    ['GET', '/article/{id}', ['SuperBlog\Controller\ArticleController', 'show']],
];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this:
 /**
 * Routing
 */
$routes = simpleDispatcher(function (RouteCollector $r){
    $routes = include('routes.php');
    foreach ($routes as $key => $route) {
       $r->addRoute($route[$key][0], $route[$key][1], $route[$key][2]);
    }
});
```

As it is a multidimensional array you are including from 'routes.php'.

Comment: i`m having the same problem now, but this is not working. The error returned is  [8192-UNKNOWN] Non-static method